# Yii: console cron application is not sending email

Tags: php, yii

My console cron application is not sending email. Mail sending works with web-app perfect. Should I configure some option or could you give me right direction?

**protected/cron.php:**

```
<?php
 require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../components/helpers.php');
 return array(
'basePath'   => dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..',
'name'       => 'Cron',
'preload'    => array('log'),
'import'     => array(
    'application.models.*',
    'application.components.*',
),
'components' => array(
    'cache'        => array(
        'class' => 'system.caching.CFileCache'
    ),

    'mail'         => array(
        'class'         => 'ext.yii-mail.YiiMail',
        'transportType' => 'php',
        'viewPath'      => 'application.views.mail',
        'logging'       => false,
        'dryRun'        => false,
    ),        
),
'params'     => array(
    'adminEmail' => 'some_email@he.re',
),
```

);

And email sending method on my model:

```
public function sendEmail()
    {
        if ($this->mail) {
            if ($this->user->email) {
                try {
                    $notification = $this->notification;
                    Yii::import('ext.yii-mail.YiiMailMessage');
                    $params           = array('notification' => $notification);
                    $message          = new YiiMailMessage;
                    $message->view    = "notification";
                    $message->subject = __('MyApp: title', array(':title' => $notification->title));
                    $message->from    = Yii::app()->params['adminEmail'];

                    $message->setBody("dasdasd");
                    $message->setTo($this->user->email);

                    if (Yii::app()->mail->send($message) > 0) {
                        $cmd = Yii::app()->db->createCommand();
                        $cmd->update($this->tableName(), array('mail' => 1), "id={$this->id}");
                        print_r($this->getAttributes());
                    }
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    Yii::log($e->getMessage(), CLogger::LEVEL_ERROR);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

cron.php on web-root:

```
<?php
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true);
require_once('../yii/framework/yii.php');

$configFile='protected/config/cron.php';
Yii::createConsoleApplication($configFile)->run();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure the mail components in your console configuration file too. The console and web views have their own configuration files. In Yii version 1.1.xx this is main.php. That controls the web application settings. The console also has a configuration file - console.php.

Comment: on my case cron.php is configuration file of console app. See my question.

Comment: no errors, only execution freezing on line Yii::app()->mail->send($message)

Comment: What's the purpose of this line: if (Yii::app()->mail->send($message) > 0. I'm on phone so isn't clear

Comment: It checks if mail sent successfully or nor, method send returns some quantity

Comment: Ok. I can't see the code on Google code. But after if send statement and in an else clause and try to retrieve the send error. I don't use that mail client. But it's normally something life if($mail->send()) { echo 'sent';}else{ echo $mail->getErrors();}